How to reference the top container query with nested CSS containers
I have a number of DIVs nested within each other:
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">
    <div id="content"></div>
  </div>
</div>

The width of "outer" is set as a percentage of the viewport width.
In the CSS I have container queries set on both "outer" and "inner":
#outer {
  container: outer / size;
}

#inner {
  container: inner / size;
}

Everything works as expected until I try to set the width of "content" as a percentage of "outer" with:
@container outer (min-width: 100px) {
  #content {
    width: 40cqw;
  }
}

What I expect to happen is that "content" gets sized with respect to "outer". What does happen is that "content" gets size with respect to "inner".
If I delete the container query on "inner" the width of "content" is set with respect to "outer".
How can I get the width of "content" to be set with respect to the width of "outer"?
Edit:
Here's a simple page that "fails":


#outer {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10%;
  right: 10%;
  top: 10%;
  bottom: 10%;
  border: 1px dotted red;
  container: outer / size;
}

#inner {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  left: 10%;
  top: 10%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px dashed blue;
  /* Uncomment the following line to see it fail(?) */
  /*container: inner / size;*/
}

#content {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: aqua;
}

@container outer (min-width: 10px) {
  #content {
    width: 40cqw;
  }
}
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">
    <div id="content"></div>
  </div>
</div>



If it's (as it appears to be) true that "container queries apply [only] to the nearest container ancestor" then there's no straightforward solution to my question. Instead I'm going to ask them to redesign the page so that container (queries) are no longer nested.

Could you give the code that sets the width of outer - because if it's set as a % of the viewport width I can't see why you can't use that to set the width of content so I must be missing something.

Maybe you could use grid layout to achieve such condition:


#outer {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10%;
  right: 10%;
  top: 10%;
  bottom: 10%;
  border: 1px dotted red;
  container: outer / size;
}

#inner {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  left: 10%;
  top: 10%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px dashed blue;
  container: inner / size;
  
  /* use grid layout */
  display: grid;
}

#content {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: aqua;
}

/* when container query is active */
@container outer (min-width: 10px) {
  #inner {
    /* set the grid layout to be 40cqw, so #container could use its size */
    grid-template-columns: 40cqw;
  }
}
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">
    <div id="content"></div>
  </div>
</div>




As the outer element has its width set in relation to the viewport, you can use those units (vw) rather than cqw to set the width of content.
This snippet sets a CSS variable to the % of the left (and right) properties of outer.
This value is then used to calculate the width of content.


<style>
  #outer {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: absolute;
    --s: 10;
    left: calc(var(--s) * 1%);
    right: calc(var(--s) * 1%);
    top: 10%;
    bottom: 10%;
    border: 1px dotted red;
    container: outer / size;
  }
  
  #inner {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
    left: 10%;
    top: 10%;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px dashed blue;
    /* Uncommented the following line where it used to fail */
    container: inner / size;
  }
  
  #content {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: aqua;
  }
  
  @container outer (min-width: 100px) {
    #content {
      width: calc((100vw - (2vw * var(--s))) * 40 / 100);
    }
  }
</style>
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">
    <div id="content"></div>
  </div>
</div>



